# Programmatically export SQL Server views to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I posed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713598/export-view-data-programmatically-in-access-sql-server) about 8 months ago, and the fact that we were running SQL Server 2000 seemed to be the limiting factor. We recently upgraded to SQL Server 2008 and I still can't find a solid solution to this problem.

We have an Access application interfacing with a SQL Server database and we need to find a way to programmatically export a given view to an Excel spreadsheet -- or at least an Excel compatible spreadsheet (CSV, tab delimited, etc.)  I can use bcp, however several of the views contain fields with linefeeds in them, which proves troublesome when importing to Excel. These views are also varied and have unpredictable columns, so to the best of my knowledge using OPENROWSET is also not an option, as you need to have an Excel template with rows predefined.

Any help here would be appreciated. I know my way around Access and SQL Server, but my knowledge is somewhat limited.

Comment: Have you considered doing this the other way around, i.e. just pulling the data from the view into Excel? i.e. Just use Data->From Other Sources->SQL Server, and set up a query in there to pull the view data in. Anytime you want to repopulate the data, you just can just click the Refresh button in Excel... I normally find this works a lot better than pushing data into Excel from a server.

Comment: This won't really work well for my users. We're operating out of a pretty extensive Access application, and they're going to need to select their data and then generate the Excel doc from Access. Good thought, though!

Comment: This question might benefit from addtional tags excel and access-vba. The best answer might be a crossing of ideas or suggestions from both "sql", "excel" and "access" audiences.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "programatically", which language were you hoping to implement the solution in?

I would suggest SQL Server SSIS as a good starting point. If you needed to code this dynamically, rather than using the BIDS/Visual Studio Designer there is plenty of support for this in the .NET libraries, allowing you to do it in c#/VB

Comment: I was hoping to do this via SQL/VBscript in Access. My C# skills are pretty nonexistant and it's been a long, long time since I've done any Visual Studio / DLL authoring. Calling BCP works great, if I weren't dealing with linefeeds in the data.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to export data into CSV you may write your own function to escape special characters in fields

(It is a pain in one place)

1. If you use SSIS to export your data into Excel it will put apostrophe and the beginning of every cell
2. If you willing to spend some money you may consider using our Advanced ETL processor
   First of all it works correctly with Excel all the time.
   Plus it has data export component which allows you to select the tables/views to 
   export using mask
   You can use scheduler to automate it or you can run a package from the command line

This on-line tutorial gives you a quick introduction to data export

http://www.dbsoftlab.com/online-tutorials/advanced-etl-processor/advanced-etl-pro-exporting-data-from-mysql-database-into-text-files.html