# Loop until the last column (Horizontally) to be used

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am working on Excel VBA. I am trying to loop through the columns horizontally in excel as until the last value in recordset. Below is my code. As I want it to start from column G and up to data in recordset. As in Below code I have represent last column as X . It may be BM/BN but can not predict at starting.

Please  help me to get the desired solution.

```
Set RS = 'recordset is set

If Not RS.BOF And Not RS.EOF Then
RS.MoveFirst
Do While Not RS.BOF And Not RS.EOF

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ReportTemplateDirectory & TestExcel.xlsx")
    xlWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = "Calculation"
    Set ShtReport = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Sheets("Calculation")

    xlApp.Workbooks(1).Sheets("Calculation").Range("G6").Value = "")
    .....
    ..... 'Loop until the last column to be used
    .....
    xlApp.Workbooks(1).Sheets("Calculation").Range("X").Value = "")

 RS.MoveNext
 Loop
 End If
```

Comment: Can't tell from the code--did you paste the recordset yet?

Comment: I have skipped the code for setting recordset through query. So just need to know the iteration part.

Comment: If you have a recordset in MS Access, you have a field / column count.

Comment: @Fionnuala I have edited the question.. And FYI using recordset entries i want to loop through last row/entry as last column in excel. Just to iterate recordset horizontally in excel.

Comment: @Lopsided Could you please tell me in more details what you want to say.

Comment: Sure. I didn't know how far along you were with that. Give me a minute to demonstrate recordsets.

Comment: @lopsided Why not copyfromrecordset? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812424/writing-copyfromrecordset-to-range/10814046#10814046

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant...not "pastefromrecordset"

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a fairly straightforward loop. I added some inline comments to note some the changes made.

```
Set RS = 'recordset is set

' Not sure if you need/want the RS.BOF condition here...
If Not RS.BOF And Not RS.EOF Then
    RS.MoveFirst

    ' Initial Excel outside of the loop.
    ' Otherwise you create an instance for each record entry.
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ReportTemplateDirectory & "TestExcel.xlsx")
    Set ShtReport = xlWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    ShtReport.Name = "Calculation"

    Dim col As Integer
    col = 7 ' Start on column G.
    Do While Not RS.EOF
        ' All output will go to row 6.
        ShtReport.Cells(col, 6).Value = "?" ' Put value from RS here.

        RS.MoveNext
        col = col + 1
    Loop

    ' If you are done with Excel, release the resources here.

End If
```

Comment: RBAR is rarely an answer when you have copyfromrecordset.

Comment: Copying to an Excel sheet and then navigating the sheet instead of Recordset is probably easier, but this should certainly work. +1

Comment: @Fionnuala - RBAR? I see you made a few comments in the main thread about `copyfromrecordset`. I didn't know about this method so I'll check it out.

Comment: RBAR: 'Row By Agonizing Row'

Comment: It's an idiom/achronym. RBAR = "row by agonizing row". Personally, I don't mind RBAR. Sometimes slow and steady wins the race :)

Comment: Hi Jason, I have a link in my comments above :)

Comment: @Fionnuala - I was just looking at it. The OP wants to move _horizontally_. The `CopyFromRecordset` method doesn't seem to have a switch to do this (unless it is the default behavior, but I imagine default is vertical output). Additionally, it doesn't seem to have params to specify which fields to write out. What if the RS contains 5 fields and you only want to output 1 for this particular method?

Comment: Jason, it is running from MS Access, so you have a field / column count and a query to select exactly the fields / columns that you need.

Comment: @Fionnuala - So you would need to have your RS tailored for just this action. What about horizontal output? I can see this as useful method, it just appears to limited in options.

Comment: In MS Access you can very easily tailor output in any way you wish. It takes seconds of work.